# Can conda coexist with pip?

Tags: python, anaconda

Maybe is a stupid question but I would like to install a python package that is in conda but not in pip. This is the package:

https://wrf-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

I don't have conda installed. My concern is that can conda coexist with pip? In other words, if I install conda and install that package, I would be able to use it with all the packages that I already have installed in pip?

thanks

Comment: If you are on windows there seems to be some pre-built binaries available for version 1.0.5 - https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by running

conda config --add create_default_packages pip

and pip will be installed in any new environment.

But, the whole point of conda is for it to work better than pip, so I would suggest using conda instead of pip at all times.